# Convey fail on simple test

Tags: go, goconvey

I am attempting to use Convey for the first time. My real test fails for an unknown reason, so I created this very simple test and it fails the same way.

```
   GO Convey
func TestSimple(t *testing.T) {
    Convey("Given Simple Test", t, func() {
        Convey("When Tested", func() {
            Convey("There should be a result", func() {
                i := 1
                So(i, ShouldEqual, i)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

I am probably doing something wrong, however I'm at a loss

UPDATE:  I found an old Convey test in another app that works.  I copied the simple test to it and ran tests. it works.

Is there something that is possibly configured wrong? It is the same server and go setup.

[image: Screen shot of test]

Comment: Have you tried to run the unit test manually with `go test -v`? In theory it should pass.

Comment: Fails also with:
panic: Top-level calls to Convey(...) need a reference to the *testing.T.
  Hint: Convey("description here", t, func() { /* notice that the second  argument was the *testing.T (t)! */ })


I think it is set they way stated in the hint.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `t` in the second and third convey, you only have it in the first convey.

Comment: According to the docs, it only belongs in the first. However, I made the change and it still failed.  The simple test fails here and works when inserted into another old app with Convey.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to your version of Go combined with your (outdated) version of Go Convey and some of its dependencies. Perhaps you had some dependencies already in your `$GOPATH/src` and now you updated to Go version 1.12.*?

This happened to me when updating from Go version 1.10 to Go version 1.12.6, I've followed the details in here and this helped me fixing my environment: https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/issues/561#issuecomment-505525085

These are the steps I followed:

- `cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/ && git checkout master && git pull`

  - this should be equivalent to: `go get github.com/smartystreets/goconvey`
- `cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/smartystreets/assertions/ && git checkout master && git pull`

  - this should be equivalent to: `go get github.com/smartystreets/assertions`
- `go get -u golang.org/x/tools...`
- `cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/jtolds/gls/ && git checkout master && git pull`

  - this should be equivalent to: `go get github.com/jtolds/gls`